# how to view google play store listing in different language

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, google-play-console

i uploaded an android app to google play store, and i have English and Chinese content for the store information (descriptions, short desc, etc... My default language is english, but I'm trying to figure out how can i see the listing of the other languages? Is there an extra param in the URL i need to type the language code in?

[image]

---

i tried adding an extra param at the end of my app's url; `&hl=zh`, but it didn't actually update the content to the Chinese content i have in the console, it's still in english:

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.{myapp}&hl=zh](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.%7Bmyapp%7D&hl=zh)

Comment: And accessing the store page from a incognito window doesn't show the correct content?

Comment: @MorrisonChang i just tried, no luck.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Japanese and can't find a way to check it with the browser. I can only change the language of my phone and then open the Play Store App.

Answer (score 9):

You must insert " &hl=en " to the end of the link to indicate that " hl " (variable that store the language) is " en " (indentify the country code for english language). And for more language change " en " with country code that you prefer.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

to

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

That extra param at the end of the url should work, but there could be a reason it doesn't work (yet).

The translations that you have added might still be in review. You can check this by going to the Publishing Overview. Then you will be able to see the changes on Google Play once they have been reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

Try with
[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.{myapp}&hl=zh_hk&gl=hk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.%7Bmyapp%7D&hl=zh_hk&gl=hk)

I don't have any Chinese translations yet to test, but for Japanese it works with **&hl=ja_jp&gl=jp**